# Asynchronous REST call Server Side

Tags: java, rest, asynchronous

I want to make an asynchronous REST call for my service. It's like client called my service, I send client acknowledgement that I received it and processing, and in back-end I am processing the request.

I am trying with below approach:

```
private static ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

@GET
@Path("/health")
public String checkHealth() {
    executor.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            
            LocalDateTime start= LocalDateTime.now();
            System.out.println("Inside");
            int count=0;
            while(ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between( LocalDateTime.now(),start)<10) {
                System.out.println("Count: " +count);
                count++;
            }
            //here a heavy work which can take a long time
        }
    });
    return "{\"Test\": \"Success\"}";
}
```

Is this a good approach? Or is there any better approach I can use to achieve this?

Comment: A better aproach should use reactive stream, something like Spring WebFlux , or Eclipse vert.x

Comment: what framework are you using?

Comment: JAXRS I am using to achieve this